# Error on internal DTD in XML File

Tags: xml, dtd

My XML file couldn't run. I got some errors on the DTD. What is wrong with my DTD code? I have tried running it on Internet explorer, but it doesn't work. When I didn't include the DTD code, it works fine. But once I include the DTD, it displays a blank page. Once i validate the xml file in  http://validator.w3.org/ , i got these error

> Line 25, Column 23: document type does not allow element "book" here
>
> <*book instock = "yes"*>
>
> The element named above was found in a context where it is not
> allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements --
> such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside
> "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed)
>
> One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML
> documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this
> error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's
> "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a
> HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head"
> section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and
> "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error)

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type ="text/css" href="Books.css"?>

<!DOCTYPE inventory [
    <!ELEMENT inventory(book)>
    <!ELEMENT book(title,author,isbn,publisher,pages,price)>
<!ATTLIST book instock CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT author(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT isbn(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT publisher(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT pages(#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price(#PCDATA)>
]>

<inventory>
    <book instock = "yes">
        <title>Beginning web programming with html, xhtml, and css </title>
        <author>Duckett, jon </author>
        <isbn>0764570781</isbn>
        <publisher>Wrox pr inc</publisher>
        <pages>840</pages>
        <price>MYR 119.80</price>
    </book>
    <book instock = "yes">
        <title>Core web programming(2nd edition)</title>
        <author>Marty hall, larry brown</author>
        <isbn>0130897930 </isbn>
        <publisher>Prentice hall ptr </publisher>
        <pages>1385</pages>
        <price> MYR 125.00</price>
    </book>
    <book instock = "no">
        <title>An introduction to web design and programming</title>
        <author>Paul s. wang, sanda katila</author>
        <isbn>0534395287</isbn>
        <publisher>Course technology</publisher>
        <pages>592</pages>
        <price> MYR 251.00</price>
    </book>
</inventory>
```

Comment: _"I got some error on DTD"_ -- Do you think maybe telling us what the error message said _might_ be helpful? Please [edit] your question and include ALL the relevant details.

Comment: i have edited the question. sorry, i am new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!ELEMENT inventory(book)>
```

This says an `inventory` element can contain exactly ONE `book`. You want

```
<!ELEMENT inventory(book)*>
```

or maybe

```
<!ELEMENT inventory(book)+>
```